# UILocalNotification: Repeat every 2 months, 4 months, 6 months?

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

I want to schedule local notifications at an interval of 2 months, 4 months and 6 months.

From the NSCalendarUnits available, I don't see how this is possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have implemented this sort of functionality using following hack.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification
(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    if ([notification.alertBody isEqualToString:@"your notification's alertBody"])
    {
       //reschedule your notification for 2 months
    }
}
```

just use the above method in your application's delegate appdelegate.m

Comment: the comparison is for identifying which notification has been fired? Isn't there are more elegant way than comparison with the alertBody?

Comment: i was using alertBody because it was unique in my case. are you using some similar localNotification's alertBody?

Comment: and yes it is to identify the localnotification

Comment: means i can subclass UILocalNotification and add ID property?

Comment: ahh.. if you think so, just try subclassing to identify your local notification.

Comment: But if the user is not reacting to the local notification? Then no method is called and I can't re-schedule the notification?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69355/discussion-between-mradlmaier-and-syedalisalman).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately is not possible. `NSCalendarUnit` works only for the unit repetition.

You have 3 possibilities taking into account that you cannot schedule more than 64 local notifications.

1. If you know that will never exceed that limit, schedule all the notifications required
2. Make an algorithm that schedule just an amount of notifications, when the user enter in your app delete the old notification and reschedule more notification. To do that identify each notif with an ID and attach it to the info dictionary.
3. Create a web service that register user option and use a server to push the notification when required (Push notification)